# Curl to Http request

Tags: http, curl

I am using below curl

```
 curl http://XXXXX:6800/schedule.json -d project=stackoverflow -d spider=careers.stackoverflow.com -d setting=DOWNLOAD_DELAY=2 -d arg1=val1
```

How can i convert this to Http request? Can any one help me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In `curl` the `-d` option means `--data`, just the data to post to the http server,in the same way that a browser does when a user has  filled  in an HTML form and presses the submit button.

This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

For example you use python, you can form the requests lik:

```
import requests
data = {
    'project': 'stackoverflow',
    'spider': 'careers.stackoverflow.com',
    'setting': 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY=2'
    'arg1': 'val1'
}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

requests.post('http://XXXX:6800/schedule.json', data=data, headers=headers)
```

For more infomation, you can look the `curl` man page.

Comment: I tried this but i am getting the below error                      XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.